# Validate xml with xsd in C# and replace invalid data with null value

Tags: c#, silverlight, xsd

How to validate data from .xml file with .xsd file using C# and replace invalid data with null value?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [XmlSchemaValidator class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidator.aspx). While it's not easy to use, it is *very* powerful.

It works via a "push" model. The API informs you what kind of XML would be valid at the current point in the validation. You then supply a valid piece of XML (element, attribute, etc), and ask again, what would be valid *now*. I have used this to create sample XML that conforms to a set of schemas.

Although I haven't tried it, I suppose you could feed your input XML to the validator, then pass some "empty" XML once you reach an invalid point in the parse.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this class can't be used in Silverlight. I wanted to use it once in an SL application but couldn't. Any alternative that works with Silverlight? By that time I just gave up code validation of XML files.

Comment: It's quite obscure, so I doubt it's available for Silverlight. Only way I could see to use it would be to use it in a WCF service and call it from SL.

Answer (score -1):

In .NET 3.5 to validate just use the following code

```
    public bool Validate(XmlReader xmlInput, XmlReader schemaDocument)
    {
        var xmlSchemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
        xmlSchemaSet.Add("", schemaDocument);
        try
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlInput);
            bool valid = true;
            doc.Validate(xmlSchemaSet, (o, e) =>
            {
                valid = false;
            });
            return valid;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

but to correct your document, you should use XmlReader's methods and custom verification, I consider.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.